# What is compilations in Apple WatchKit?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, apple-watch-complication

What is compilations in Apple WatchKit?

Can I have both compilation interface and normal app `WKInterfaceController` in same Apple Watch app?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question see: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ComplicationEssentials.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH27-SW1

From the docs:

> Complications are small elements that appear on the watch face and provide quick access to frequently used data. Users can customize most watch faces and install the complications that they want to see. The system provides built-in complications for weather information, upcoming calendar events, the user’s activity, and many more types of data. Apps can also add support for complications and display app-specific data.
>
> To implement a complication, import the ClockKit framework into your WatchKit extension. The ClockKit framework defines the classes you use to implement your complication and provide the data that Apple Watch needs. For information about the classes of this framework, see ClockKit Framework Reference.

For your second question: Yes. You just need to implement a class which is a CLKComplicationDataSource delegate, which will provide the data for the various complication types.

Comment: Please at least quote some relevant part of that external link here to give a complete answer; if that link ever dies your answer essentially contains no content whatsoever.